# Bitmap always show null?

Tags: android, bitmap

In my program, I have to change image path to bitmap. The image path is already exit but when I change to bitmap, bitmap always show null. I don't know what happen.Here is my code.

```
String dirName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+picturePath;
     File sddir = new File(dirName);

         Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sddir.getAbsolutePath());
            //Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myBitmap);
         Log.i("mybitmap",myBitmap+"");

     Log.i("dirName",dirName+"");
     Log.i("FileName",sddir+"");
```

Please, give me some advice...

Edit: Logcat output:

```
01-19 11:56:18.085: I/mybitmap(1469): null
01-19 11:56:18.085: I/dirName(1469): /mnt/sdcard/mnt/sdcard/447650.jpg
01-19 11:56:18.085: I/FileName(1469): /mnt/sdcard/mnt/sdcard/447650.jpg
01-19 12:19:59.754: I/PicturePath(1671): /mnt/sdcard/62afbdb0c0d287195c0eb7793427b8b8.jpg
```

Comment: What does "the image path is already exit" mean?

Comment: I mean image path exit. I know it because Log.i show picturepath.

Comment: what is returned value of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+picturePath`? can you post `dirName` String value...

Comment: I post Logcat output.

Comment: It looks like you are appending SD card path one more time to `dirName`. try with `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)`

Comment: It also tried it. It didn't work. :)

Comment: there is wrong in picture path. check that once...

Comment: I posted picturepath. I don't think picturepath is wrong. It's working.

Comment: When I change BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath), Log cat show  01-19 12:20:03.394: I/mybitmap(1671): android.graphics.Bitmap@4175b5e0

Comment: finally got Bitmap object. so you solved your problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your bitmap path is wrong, you are appending the path to sdcard twice. Try this:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/447650.jpg");
```

OR

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
```

OR

Make `picturePath` the path relative to the path of sdcard.